# Separating values from a single return column into multiple rows based on select statement

Tags: sql

I have a query with a select statement that returns a string in a single column, but I wanted to see if there is a way that I can separate the value based on unique identifier and push it to its own column/row based on other select criteria.

For example, I have a select statement that returns a column value TRACKING_NUMBER as

```
1ZX9254803061897701ZX9254803061897981ZX9254803061898141ZX925480306189832
```

Is there a way for the column value to be separated into four different values and then placed in a separate row for each value in the output?

So instead of one row with the long string in the column value, I would have four rows with each piece of the string under its own entry, but all other columns of the select statement would remain the same for each entry.

```
1ZX925480306189770
1ZX925480306189798
1ZX925480306189814
1ZX925480306189832
```

I tried using a substring command to separate it but that did not work.

Comment: Yes, it can probably be done. Will the original string always have the same length?

Comment: Substring is likely the appropriate approach here. That said, this is a really really really really stupid way to store this data. At minimum you could at least delimit it, however storing it this way completely defeats the point of using a database. If possible, it is strongly recommended to stop and take a deeper look at how you are storing this data to begin with.

Comment: That said, if you are going to get any sort of answer however, please provide ddl for the table you are working with, a few rows of sample data, and your desired output based on that sample data.

Comment: If you add a tag for your specific DBMS, such as [sql-server], [oracle], [mysql], etc., you will reach a larger audience including those who specialize in the specific DBMS you are working on.  It is also useful to know the version. For example, if SQL Server 2022, a `CROSS APPLY` using the `GENERATE_SERIES()` and `SUBSTRING()` functions can easily split the string.  I'm assuming these are fixed-length, as they appear to be UPS tracking codes. For earliCTE may be needed.

Comment: @ClearlyClueless Fixed Width is a relatively common file format. If this is part of an ETL process to normalise the ingested data, it makes perfect sense.

Comment: There are several ways to do this, but each is specific to a different DBMS. Please specify which DBMS you're using. *(If in doubt, refer to the tool tip on the `sql` tag.)*

Comment: This is a fair point and something I had not considered. I stand by what I said however, as if this is how the data is being captured into the database and the intent of this query is to read it out for consumption, then their process needs to be revisited some if possible.

Answer (score 0):

For SQL Server 2022 and later, you can use a `CROSS APPLY` together with the `GENERATE_SERIES()` and `SUBSTRING()` functions to split the string.

```
DECLARE @TrackingNumbers VARCHAR(MAX)
    = '1ZX9254803061897701ZX9254803061897981ZX9254803061898141ZX925480306189832'
DECLARE @Width INT = 18

SELECT
    S.value AS Position,
    SUBSTRING(@TrackingNumbers, S.value, @Width) AS TrackingNumber
FROM GENERATE_SERIES(1, CAST(LEN(@TrackingNumbers) AS INT), @Width) S
```

Or for a table source:

```
DECLARE @Width INT = 18

SELECT
    D.Id,
    S.value AS Position,
    SUBSTRING(D.TrackingNumbers, S.value, @Width) AS TrackingNumber
FROM Data D
CROSS APPLY GENERATE_SERIES(1, CAST(LEN(D.TrackingNumbers) AS INT), @Width) S
ORDER BY D.Id, S.value
```

Sample results:

| Id | Position | TrackingNumber |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1ZX925480306189770 |
| 1 | 19 | 1ZX925480306189798 |
| 1 | 37 | 1ZX925480306189814 |
| 1 | 55 | 1ZX925480306189832 |
| 2 | 1 | 1AA100000000000001 |
| 2 | 19 | 2BB200000000000002 |

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/l1dymBls) for a demo.